# Reload PATH for the entire playbook

Tags: ansible

As part of most of the Ansible playbooks I need to install Node and Mongo from internally hosted tarballs. Sudo privileges and internet access are not available. All of the Ansible runs happen against localhost.

One of the problems of this setup is that after untarring node/mongo, they need to be added to PATH or subsequent roles/tasks won't be able to rely on them. Unfortunately, I don't seem to be able to find a way to amend PATH within an Ansible playbook run.

I've tried using shell and command tasks to export PATH and source .bashrc, neither of those seem to help. Is there a way to use my node installation within the same playbook? yum task seems to do the trick, but it's not available to me now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using 'environment'?

You can get your local PATH into a variable

```
environment:  
    PATH: "{{ lookup('env', 'PATH') }}"
```

or you can set the PATH

```
environment:  
   PATH: "{{ node_path }}:{{mongo_path}}:{{ lookup('env', 'PATH') }}"
```

The above assumes you can register the path to mongo & Node as vars, and make them available to later plays.

Info on using environment & PATH locally and remotely is here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/577188/how-can-i-prepend-to-path-while-running-ansibles-pip-module

```
- hosts: localhost  
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    path1: "{{lookup('env', 'PATH')}}"
  tasks:
  - shell: echo $PATH
    environment:
      PATH: 'mypath2'
    register: path2
  - shell: echo $PATH
    environment:
      PATH: 'mypath3'
    register: path3
  - shell: echo $PATH
    environment:
      PATH: "{{ path1 }}"
    register: path4


  - debug: msg={{path1}}
  - debug: msg={{path2}}
  - debug: msg={{path3}}
  - debug: msg={{path4}}
  - debug: msg={{lookup('env', 'PATH')}}
```